# How to get data from range then put them in array and them sort them in excel vba?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to have the unique values from a column (column c from sheet1) and have the unique values in an array so that I can reuse them again from that array.

I'm new to stak so, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just to get you started. To see how it works, first select your range of data and then step through this code. Note that after sorting, it puts the range into a variant (a) and then just to confirm that it's in there, the variant is placed into a range next to the original. You can then use the variant as needed.

```
Sub sort()
  Dim r As Range, a As Variant
  Set r = Selection
  With ActiveSheet.sort
    .SetRange r
    .Apply
  End With
  a = r
  r.Offset(0, 1) = a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Dictionary` object

here's a Function that retrieves all unique values from a passed `Range` reference

```
Function uniqueValues(columnRng As Range) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In columnRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            .Item(cell.Value) = 1
        Next
        uniqueValues = .Keys
    End With
End Function
```

This function may be exploited in your "mian" code as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim values As Variant

    values = uniqueValues(Columns("C")) 
End Sub
```